# Json with no root element ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

So i am very new to ios development and i am creating my first app which connects to a server and pulls some information. I have followed a number of different tutorials and have managed to pull back some json from different places. The problem im having is the information i need to pull has no root element, what do i need to change to get the information to my app?

Below is the code i am using:

```
   #import "leagueTableViewController.h"

   #define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

    #define kjsonURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising"]
     @interface leagueTableViewController ()

      @end

      @implementation leagueTableViewController{

    NSMutableArray *jsonResults;
     }

    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
    {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
     if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
     }
      return self;
        }

      - (void)viewDidLoad
       {
      [super viewDidLoad];

        dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

           NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:

                    kjsonURL];

          [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)

                           withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];

             });
           }




        - (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

           NSError* error;

           NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization

                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                      options:kNilOptions

                      error:&error];

       jsonResults = [json objectForKey:@"loans"];

       [self.tableView reloadData];

        }


    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
      {
      [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

      #pragma mark - Table view data source

      - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        {

      // Return the number of sections.
       return 1;
       }   

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:   (NSInteger)section
   {
   return [jsonResults count];
  }

      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

       {
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        NSDictionary *appsdict = [jsonResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       NSString *VersionString = [appsdict objectForKey:@"funded_amount"];

       NSString *priceString = [appsdict objectForKey:@"loan_amount"];


       cell.textLabel.text = [appsdict objectForKey:@"name"];

      cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version: %@ Price: $ %@ USD",VersionString,priceString];



     return cell;


     }

       #pragma mark - Table view delegate

      - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
     {
     //    NSDictionary *appsdict = [jsonResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     //    
    //    NSString *appURL = [appsdict objectForKey:@"trackViewUrl"];
     //    
    //    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appURL]];
     }

    @end
```

This is an example of the json the above code is using, as you can see the root elements:

```
      {
       "paging": {
      "page": 1,
      "total": 873,
      "page_size": 20,
       "pages": 44
        },
       "loans": [{
        "id": 544449,
        "name": "Sajad",
        "description": {
            "languages": ["en"]
          },
          "status": "fundraising",
          "funded_amount": 0,
          "basket_amount": 0,
          "image": {
            "id": 1325179,
            "template_id": 1
           },
          "activity": "Cloth & Dressmaking Supplies",
          "sector": "Retail",
           "use": "to renovate his shop and increase his textile inventory",
           "location": {
            "country_code": "IQ",
            "country": "Iraq",
            "geo": {
                "level": "country",
                "pairs": "33 44",
                "type": "point"
            }
           },
           "partner_id": 166,
          "posted_date": "2013-04-04T15:40:01Z",
           "planned_expiration_date": "2013-05-04T15:40:01Z",
           "loan_amount": 2400,
           "borrower_count": 1
            }
```

And this is the json i need to get but it has no root element, what do i need to do to display this in my app:

```
     [{
    "position": 1,
    "team_id": 10260,
    "team": "Manchester United",
    "teamshort": "Man Utd",
    "played": 30,
    "won": 25,
    "drawn": 2,
    "lost": 3,
    "for": 70,
    "against": 31,
    "difference": 39,
    "home": {
        "played": 15,
        "won": 14,
        "drawn": 0,
        "lost": 1,
        "for": 39,
        "against": 15,
        "difference": 24
    },
    "away": {
        "played": 15,
        "won": 11,
        "drawn": 2,
        "lost": 2,
        "for": 31,
        "against": 16,
        "difference": 15
    },
    "points": 77,
    "info": "championsleague"
}
```

Comment: So, the JSON you're retrieving returns an error with the NSJSONSerialization call?

Comment: these are **two totally different** responses... by the way...

Comment: The first set of json works perfect but the second set returns error 

   __NSCFArray objectForKey:

Comment: Thats where im having the problem im trying to display the second reponse but all the tutorials and examples i have found only work with the first type of response.

Comment: @paulpwr, because the second one has a **totally different** structure than the first one... of course, you have to manage the second one in another way.

Comment: Yea thats what i was trying to ask, i just made a total mess of it. How do i go about managing the second structure? Any tutorials or examples would be handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JSON you need to know the structure beforehand. The API sending you the data will let you know this.

The reason you receive the error is due to the fact you're treating an NSArray like an NSDictionary. Here's an example.

This should be parsed to NSArray:

```
[{
    username: 'johndoe'
}]
```

This would be NSDictioanry:

```
{
   username: 'johndoe'
}
```

The data you have is similar to the first case I presented. So to get data you'd need something like:

```
NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

[[json objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey:@"thekey"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The second block will parse correctly if you strip the first bracket off before you try to read it:

```
NSData *strippedData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, data.length-1)];
```

As far as the error you're receiving is concerned, that's not a NSJSONSerialization error, it's saying that the object returned is an NSArray type (even though your were expecting an NSDictionary type) and you're trying to invoke `objectForKey:` on it, which is not a method of NSArray. You should analyze the array and see if it contains the info you need. That might look something like this:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
jsonResults = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"loans"];
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The second response that "has no root element" is **not valid JSON**. That's why it can't be parsed. There is no such thing as JSON with no root element-- only valid JSON and broken, invalid JSON. You have a couple of options:

1. As @daltonclaybrook suggested, strip out the leading "[". Or alternately, add an extra "]" at the end. Either change will result in valid JSON. I don't like this approach because if the server is giving you broken JSON then it might not be consistently broken, or they might fix it at some point.
2. **Fix the JSON on the server side**. If you have any connection to the server at all, tell them that their JSON is broken and make them fix it. If you can't get it fixed, my condolences, because dealing with screwed up servers is no fun at all. If there's any possibility of getting the mess resolved, **do that** instead of trying to figure out how it's broken *this time* and fixing it on your end.